# Bidirectional data transfer

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I have two nodes and one database. I want to transfer data between them. DML operations on server node-1 should transfer to node-2 and DML operations on node-2 should transfer to node-1 as well.

Is this possible and what is the best (most fast, safe, and stable) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributing reads is easy; distributing writes is not. In SQL Server, most availability technologies require a specific node or database to be the "master" where all writes go.  Some possible options:

- [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication)
- [Peer-to-Peer Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication)
- [Transactional Replication with Updatable Subscribers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/updatable-subscriptions-for-transactional-replication) *(deprecated)*

What is "best"? That's not really the kind of question we can answer here unless you get much, much more specific about what you mean by "best."

Comment: It means fast, safe and stable. Thank you for answer. I'm gonna try these.

Comment: But again, sometimes you have to pick one or two of those things as the most important thing, and trade off the other(s). And you don't mention complexity or cost, which are surely also decision factors, as is the likelihood of things to go wrong (replication is high on this IMHO) and future support.

Comment: You're right but I was hoping that someone with experience could tell me about it. Although, these info enough for me, thank you. I can try these on my test server and I can research.